# Change Windows Failover Cluster Owner Using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, failovercluster

I'm currently trying to move ownership from one node in a Windows Failover Cluster to another.  The nodes are in different subnets and different Active Directory sites.

Prior to issuing the move command, clustering commandlets work properly (i.e. `Get-Cluster $ClusterName`).

After issuing the failover command, clustering commandlets and all time out:

```
Move-ClusterGroup -Cluster $ClusterName -Name "Cluster Group"`
```

I've verified that the cluster name properly resolves in DNS and flushed DNS locally, but the problem still persists.  After a few minutes, it starts working again.

Is this being blocked by Active Directory replication, and if so, is the preferred method of forcing a sync to use `REPADMIN`?

Comment: You got tumbleweed for this? This is a fine question. I don't think I could get tumbleweed for the life of me on this site.